# Angular 2 - Module not found

Tags: javascript, json, angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to add boostrap to my project but it shows me an error:[image]

I'm changing only this in .angular-cli.json:

```
"styles": [

        "styles.css",
        "../angular2/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      ],
```

Working on @4.0.0-alpha.5 :

"styles": [

```
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

on version @4.0.0:

[image]

path is the same:

[image]

Comment: Please check this link https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your src, node_modules and .angular-cli.json are in same directory/folder then this should be right address of the file

```
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
```

If all the above things are not in main project folder, then keep'em in same folder.

For the other version, I would suggest check this link out 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020

The issue seems to be caused by this section of bootstrap's package.json file

```
 "browserslist": [
    "last 1 major version",
    ">= 1%",
    "Chrome >= 45",
    "Firefox >= 38",
    "Edge >= 12",
    "Explorer >= 10",
    "iOS >= 9",
    "Safari >= 9",
    "Android >= 4.4",
    "Opera >= 30"
  ],
```

The autoprefixer plugin uses this list and unless you have a version 7.0 or higher it does not support the last n major version syntax.

Upgrading autoprefixer should fix the issue.

Comment: hmmm... i've trying that before on bootstrap version 4.0.0 and didn't work, now i changed that to 4.0.0-alpha.5 and it works ... Why this is happening ??

Comment: may be path to file is different in other version

Comment: Path is the same but it returns and error :/ i was trying many other combinations in 4.0.0 version and didn't work. Ok thanks for help it was easy but that version surprised me :) hehe thanks!

Comment: Yup i'm waiting, i can accept the answer in 4 minutes

Comment: actually I use these versions of bootstrap : - `"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",` and `"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.2",`

Comment: look i edited code

Comment: checkout the updated answer and link, you'll get everything there

Comment: yup works :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Update your code as shown below:

   "styles": [
           "styles.css",
           "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
         ],
2. This will resolve your problem

   npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6